# Python on Windows: Which pip

Tags: python, pip

I have different Python environments installed in different directories in Windows. How can I ensure I am using the pip for one particular version of Python?

Unfortunately, due to the groups I work with using a variety of Python flavors, I need all of the Python installations I have. I'm finding it very difficult, however, to use a version of pip that's not in my PATH.

Comment: Have you looked into `virtualenv`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work with multiple Python installations, all of them in my PATH. A good way to manage this is to rename (or copy) the `python.exe` and `pip.exe` executables such that they describe the environment.

For example, for Python 3.5, my python executable is named `python35.exe` and the pip executable is `pip35.exe` For Python 2.7 The executable name is `python27.exe` and the pip executable is `pip27.exe`

When you install using the Windows installer from Python.org, PIP actually ships with a similar naming convention by default `pip2.7.exe` for Python 2.7 or `pip3.5.exe` for Python 3.5

I follow the same scheme for the various installations I have. If I want to install a package in Python 3.5 I run `pip35 install <package>`

You can also use the full path to the Python or pip executable and use `pip` that way. IE

```
C:\Python35\python.exe -m pip install <package>
#or
C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install <package>
```

Another method of installing via pip is in a script/shell that you call using the appropriate version of Python.

```
import pip
pip.main(["install", "MyPackage"])
```

Comment: I ended up using your second suggestion: I navigated to the directory and ran pip from there. From now on, however, my favorite by far is import pip! That's awesome! I never knew that.

Comment: On Windows, how does pip know which python.exe to run? As an experiment, I tried renaming my python folder from Python37 to 3.7.3. The new folder is in the path (along with the /Scripts folder), but when I run pip, it seems to still be looking for python37/python.exe. I know py.exe uses the registry, so I changed the relevant registry entries for it so that it can find the new 3.7.3 folder. But that didn't seem to affect pip. It still can't find python.exe.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to check out which `pip` you are using by using the `--version` option, that is typing in

`pip --version` in the command line.

In Windows 10, this would return the version of the `pip` installed along with the path from which `pip.exe` is called.

You could then follow the suggestion by @sytech to rename the `pip.exe` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several Python interpreters in PATH you can use these to access the correct `pip`, for example `python -m pip` or `python3 -m pip`.

If you are talking about virtual environments, I believe that the only way to achieve that is to `activate` the relevant environment before using `pip`.